# Banner appear with push notification ios

Tags: ios, ios8, notifications, push

I'm developing push notification to my app and I have this:

When I send a notification a badge appear, if the screen is locked, an alert appear but if the user is with the screen unlocked no alerts or banners appear and only appear the number 1 in de badge (I tried  to put "+1", '+1' and +1 but it didn't work.

This is the payload structure:

```
$body['aps'] = array(
        'badge' => 1,
        'alert' => $message,
        'sound' => 'default'
    );
```

On the app's settings I have banners checked.

Sumary:

2 problems:

- No alerts or banner are shown with the device unlocked
- The number of badge is 1 always.

Hope you can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: The badge on the apps icon is always set the what every value is set in the push notification. If you want to increment the badge number you will need to keep track of the badge number at the servers side. And increase it there before sending the push notification.

Answer (score 0):

```
$body['aps'] = array(
        'badge' => 1,
        'alert' => $message,
        'sound' => 'default'
    );
```

If you app is closed or in background the badge will be updated automatically.

```
'badge' => 1 will show 1
'badge' => 2 will show 2
'badge' => n will show n where n is any positive integer
```

if you app is running/active/foreground

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] = badge;
```

Now your server should know about the pending notification. Your app cannot handle this alone.

As per the Apple docs, if your app is in foreground you will have to handle it by yourself as you want, the notification will appear in notification area only if the app is in background or closed.

Comment: Thanks! i will do it. Something about the alerts with the screen unlocked?

Comment: Notification should appear in that case.